# Is there a way to permanently delete a container versions so NO residual remains while retaining the same GTM container ID?

Tags: google-tag-manager

Typical Use Case:

- When setting up a new GTM container, we start by importing a container with a large number of custom javascript variables for initial setup and testing.
- These custom javascript variables need to be completely cleared from the container before handing off to the end user -- they contain internally proprietary code and internal API access points.
- Normally, after the deliverable GTM container version is created, we simply export the final version, import to a new container (creating a new empty container with a new container ID), update the GTM container ID in the app or website, and all is good.

Current Exception:

- We are currently working with an end user where changing / updating the GTM container ID will not be possible.

Question:

- Is there a way, via the GTM GUI, the GTM API, or some other reasonable route, to permanently delete container versions so NO residual remains from those versions (and they can not be undeleted), while retaining the same GTM container ID?

--
Previous research involved:

- searching [Google-Tag-Manager] here
- Searching [Google Tag Manager Community.](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/community?hl=en)
- Searching [Google GTM Developers](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager)
- Reading & Testing [Container Versions: delete](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/api/v1/reference/accounts/containers/versions/delete?hl=en&apix_params=%7B%22accountId%22%3A%224702179791%22%2C%22containerId%22%3A%2231946520%22%2C%22containerVersionId%22%3A%222%22%7D)
  Note: This will delete the version, but the deleted version remains in the account and can easily be undeleted.

Comment: From the top of my head, use a zone (in GTM360, but somebody built a template for a similar function in standard GTM), load the basic container and do your code tests in the zone. Only migrate from the zone (and then remove it, leaving the base container unchanged in the loading script) once all your testing is through. Not tested, and I cannot imagine nobody else came up with this, so a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Regarding my own comment, it does fullfill the "no trace" requirement since there will be a version with the zone, but it will leave no trace of the tags, triggers and variables, and that might be good enough.

Comment: Another solution would be to use a proxy (or use server-side GTM as a proxy to funnel the client-side GTM), because that would allow you to swap the files in the proxy configuration instead of the page code. Not feasible for everybody, so again, not necessarily an answer.

Comment: Eike, you really should compose it into an answer. It's a good answer. I didn't even think about GTM zones in this context, but the idea seems pretty feasible.